# Export Scrapy JSON Feed - Fails for Dynamic FEED_URI for AWS S3 using ScrapingHub

Tags: amazon-s3, scrapy, scrapinghub

I have written a scrapy scraper that writes data out using the `JsonItemExporter` and I have worked out how to export this data to my AWS S3 using the following Spider Settings in ScrapingHub

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = Abababababababababababababababababababab
FEED_FORMAT = json
FEED_URI = s3://scraper-dexi/my-folder/jobs-001.json
```

What I need to do is dynamically set the date / time on the output file and I would love it if it was using a date and time format like this `jobs-20171215-1000.json` but I don't know how to set a dynamic FEED_URI with scrapinghub.

There is not much information online and the only example I can find is here on the [scraping hub](https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000200447-exporting-scraped-items-to-an-aws-s3-account-ui-mode-) site but unfortunately it does not work.

When I apply these settings based on the example in the documentation

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = Abababababababababababababababababababab
FEED_FORMAT = json
FEED_URI = s3://scraper-dexi/my-folder/jobs-%(time).json
```

> Note the %(time) in my URI

The scraping fails with the following errors

```
[scrapy.utils.signal] Error caught on signal handler: <bound method ?.open_spider of <scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter object at 0x7fd11625d410>> Less
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 150, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py", line 190, in open_spider
    uri = self.urifmt % self._get_uri_params(spider)
ValueError: unsupported format character 'j' (0x6a) at index 53

[scrapy.utils.signal] Error caught on signal handler: <bound method ?.item_scraped of <scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter object at 0x7fd11625d410>> Less
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 150, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.py", line 220, in item_scraped
    slot = self.slot
AttributeError: 'FeedExporter' object has no attribute 'slot'
```

Comment: did you run your spider as root ?

Comment: I don't get what you mean, I'll include the main spider code if that helps

Comment: in scrapinghub if you want  you can also use ftp like this ftp://user:psw@ip/%(name)s-%(time)s.json

Comment: on monday I will try that , but I am using scraping hub and I wonder that would work for ftp but not for aws s3?

Comment: i use ftp in scraping hub, let me know if it works please

Answer (score 2):

I misunderstood the importance of the `s` in the documentation and did not realize that it was part of the token signature.

I altered

```
FEED_URI = s3://scraper-dexi/my-folder/jobs-%(time).json
```

to

```
FEED_URI = s3://scraper-dexi/my-folder/jobs-%(time)s.json
```

as per the documentation and solved the problem

> %(time)

changed to

> %(time)s